# How to get the name of an class statically in php?

Tags: php, class, introspection

With this code:

```
<?php

class a {
  public static function type() {
    echo get_class();
  }
}

class b extends a {
}

echo b::type();
```

It outputs `a`. I would like the name of the calling class: `b`. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running PHP 5.3 or higher: `get_called_class()` will do the job